# laravel - Get all checked items in datatable on submit

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, laravel-5

I have a step form with a list of items in a jQuery datatable. Users will select their desired items with a checkbox and upon clicking next, the selected items will be displayed to be finalized. This is done through ajax (form.serialize). It works, however, only the items selected on the active page are considered.Ex. page 2 is being displayed, only checkboxes in that page gets submitted

I used foreach to get the checked items

```
foreach($request->input('ItemNo') as $key => $item_no)
```

Here is my table

```
<table id="supplies_t" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><input class="main_chkbx" name="main_chkbx" type="checkbox"></th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Unit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @if(isset($supplies))
      @foreach($supplies as $supply)
        <tr id="{{ $supply->ItemName }}">
          <td><input name="ItemNo[]" class="ind_chkbx" value="SUPPLY-{{ $supply->SupplyNo }}" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>{{ $supply->ItemName }}</td>
          <td>{{ $supply->Description }}</td>
          <td>{{ $supply->UnitName }}</td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
    @endif
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: As I've said, only the checked checkboxes in the active page are submitted. Ex. page 2 is being displayed, only checkboxes in that page gets submitted.

Comment: So you need to store previously selected items somewhere - in a session, for example.

Comment: I'm still searching for other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### CAUSE

jQuery DataTables removes non-visible rows from DOM for performance reasons. When form is submitted, only data for visible checkboxes is sent to the server.

Solution is to use [`$()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) API method to get access to all elements in the table.

#### SOLUTION 1. Submit form

You need to turn elements `<input type="checkbox">` that are checked and don't exist in DOM into `<input type="hidden">` upon form submission.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   // ... skipped ...
});

$('form').on('submit', function(e){
   var $form = $(this);

   // Iterate over all checkboxes in the table
   table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
      // If checkbox doesn't exist in DOM
      if(!$.contains(document, this)){
         // If checkbox is checked
         if(this.checked){
            // Create a hidden element 
            $form.append(
               $('<input>')
                  .attr('type', 'hidden')
                  .attr('name', this.name)
                  .val(this.value)
            );
         }
      } 
   });          
});
```

#### SOLUTION 2: Send data via Ajax

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   // ... skipped ...
});

$('#btn-submit').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   $.ajax({
      url: '/path/to/your/script.php',
      data: table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').serialize();
   }).done(function(data){
      console.log('Response', data);
   });
});
```

#### DEMO

See [jQuery DataTables: How to submit all pages form data](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-submit-all-pages-form-data/) for more details and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks! I have already solved it but forgot to add the solution so thanks for your answer! I did method 1 by the way.